# UWP - Share PNG image (not a .bmp)

Tags: c#, image, format

In UWP are we obliged to share a .bmp image. I've managed to share a PNG file but the `SetBitmap()` convert the PNG in a .bmp file and I would like to share a .png file.

I have tried the `SetData()` but I can't find the correct `StandardDataFormats` to set the PNG.

Any idea how to solve this?